# Debugging PHP ability suddenly disappeared from Vsual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I've been using Xdebug debugging with PHP on Visual Studio Code. Worked basically okay. Then on the 22dn of January, I apparently got a new version. I didn't ask for it, but I seemed to have gotten it anyway.
And the latest version does not work.
Whenever I try to start a debugging session, I now get this error:

> "Cannot activate the 'PHP Xdebug' extension because it depends on an unknown 'felixfbecker.php-debug' extension."

Ehh? What? Does anybody have an explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PHP debug extension has moved to a new organisation: `xdebug.php-debug`.

You might just have to uninstall the current one, and then install the one with the new name: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xdebug.php-debug

Comment: Hi Derick Thank you very much. It worked nicely, but what is an organisation?

Comment: Every extension is published by an "organisation" - it is a way of linking plugins to people, or in this case, a set of people. It's similar to the first part of a GitHub repository name, such as `xdebug` in `https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug.org`, or `php` in `https://github.com/php/php-src`.

Comment: Okay, I get it. Thank you very much.
The new version is a real progress. Much better.
I hope I have given you enough points? If not, let me know.